# Get youtube channel stats

Tags: youtube, google-api

I need some public statistics data of youtube channels, like subscriberCount and views.

I think I only need the channel_id to get this data: 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=[channelId]&key=[APIkey]

After a user logged in I have the e-mail address, googleplusId and a displayName of each user. I can do a query on the displayname but it returns too many results.

Can anyone point me the right direction, thanks so much.
(Why is it so hard to get public data from YouTube?)

Comment: If your user logs in, you should use [oauth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps) instead of API key. Then [channel list API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) has a `mine` parameter, set it to `true` to get the user channel list. Give it a try on [google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=statistics&mine=true&_h=3&)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Do I need to send the access token with the request?

Comment: Add the http header `Authorization: Bearer access_token`. Usually, you use google library to make those call (dont know what programming language you are using)